# How can I send data from static method to another class via intent?

Tags: android-intent, send

I have created one method in one activity which have to be static but now I have to send data to another via intent but it is not allowed from static method.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that.
But maybe you can put all this static data into public variables, and then access them from the another class , by calling :
Class.NAME_OF_VARIABLE.